# GetElementsByClassName -- Perl?

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to do what would be a `getElementsByClassName` in Javascript, in perl but it doesn't work, from the code bellow all i get is END, it doesn't get in the foreach loop, what am i doing wrong, and is there a better way than HTML::TagParser?

```
...
my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( "****.html" );
$topic = URI::Fetch->fetch($topic);

my @list = $html->getElementsByClassName( 'separateur_links' );
foreach my $elem ( @list ) {
    my $text = $elem->innerText;
    print $text . "\n";
}
print "END\n";
...
```

Edit :

When i use `Data::Dumper print Dumper($html);` I get : `$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'HTML::TagParser' );`

Edit 2 :

`$topic = URI::Fetch->fetch($topic);`
wasn't in the original question, i overlooked it not knowing that it was the problem

Comment: Can you show an extract of the HTML?

Comment: [This](http://www.libertyland.tv/films/89601-telecharger-parker.html) is the page i am trying to query, ok i'll use the Dumper

Comment: The result of Dumper($html); `$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'HTML::TagParser' );`

Comment: THANKS A LOT **toolic**, yeah the problem was in the parsing it works well now :D, i had an extra `URI::Fetch->fetch($url)` that was left there from other tests.

Comment: Can you put the solution in an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `URI::Fetch->fetch` i used it for other tests and forgot to remove it :

```
my $topic = "*******.html";
print "** Checking available links in : " . $topic . "\n";
# $topic = URI::Fetch->fetch($topic);

my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( $topic );
print Dumper($html);
my @list = $html->getElementsByClassName( 'separateur_links' );
foreach my $elem ( @list ) {
    my $text = $elem->innerText;
    print $text . "\n";
}
```

Comment: No I didn't, I think you got me wrong, that line was the problem, i commented it and the code worked, if `HTML::TagParser` does use `URI::Fetch` it might have been called twice, to be sure, i added that line again and had the same Dumper output above meaning there is a problem in the parsing.